# Sub- and superscript in a different font and in different locations

Tags: fonts, math-mode

1. In an equation, I need sub- and superscript in a different font, other equation part as a different font. I am using the MiKTeX version 2.9. How to get this style in the output?
2. The superscript position is changing while the equation part containing sub- and superscript characters. I.e.:

   ```
   $$A+B_{\alpha+\beta}\rightarrow C+D_{\alpha+\beta}^{\prime}$$
   ```

in the first and second part subscript in different positions

Comment: You should not use `$$ $$` for an equation. Use `$ $` for inline math and `\[ \]` for display math.

Comment: `\[A+B^{\phantom{\prime}}_{\alpha+\beta}\rightarrow C+D^\prime_{\alpha+\beta}\]`

Answer (score 5):

1. It's not clear what you want
2. Subscripts are set a bit higher if there's no superscript; just provide a dummy one:

   ```
   \[
   A+B_{\alpha+\beta}^{} \rightarrow C+D_{\alpha+\beta}^{\prime}
   \]
   ```

   [image]

   Note that you can type `D_{\alpha+\beta}'` as `^{\prime}` can be shortened into `'`; also `^{\prime\prime}` can be `''` and so on.